# how to execute multiples sql in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, sql-server

I have a vector  and I need to use with a for to read and execute in a sql query this is my code:

```
for (int i=0; i < total; i++) {
    NSString *consultaRelacionEnvios;
    consultaRelacionEnvios = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM RELACIONENVIOS WHERE ID=%@",almacenIDAviso];
    SQLClient* client = [SQLClient sharedInstance];
    client.delegate = self;
    [client connect:URLConsulta username:@"usernameDB" password:@"passwordDB" database:nameDB completion:^(BOOL success) {
        if (success)
        {
             [client execute:consultaRelacionEnvios completion:^(NSArray* results) {
                 [self process0:results];
                 [client disconnect];
             }];
        }
    }];
}

- (void)process0:(NSArray*)data {
    for (NSArray* table in data)
        for (NSDictionary* row in table)
            for (NSString* column in row)
                [almacenRelacionEnvios addObject:row[column]];
    NSLog(@"%@",almacenRelacionEnvios);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question? What's wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: And what does that mean?

Comment: only show in nslog "(lldb)"

Comment: Then your app crashed or it hit a breakpoint. See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1